# don't sucsses to get jpg from internet- lwuit

Tags: connection, lwuit

I am developing with lwuit to Nokia and Blackberry.

I am working with server and connections. If I call to server that I am working, all work fine. But, if I try to call to external url that receive jpg, the connection request is stuck and I get responde code 400. 
The connection is failed in function performOperation() of class ConnectionRequest.

Why its happen?

If I call to my server and get image its work fine but when I call to external jpg it's don't work.
Is there any solution to this?

All this happen in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are looking for.

But I think you must check the URL of the image.  Also, the class `com.sun.lwuit.io.services.ImageDownloadService` might be very useful to you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: At least i'm trying to help him

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help.  My comment above was written during a review at a time when your answer was still just a single sentence.

Comment: What i found that the problem was in urls that use in HttpProtocol. When i run the application on Nokia device, i get the images. I think that maybe the problem is only on  blackberry simulators and http protocol or that we have problem at blackberry with http protocol.

Answer (score 0):

RIM network connections differ from Nokia/standard J2ME due to all sorts of proprietary behaviors added by RIM. [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/)'s IO API hides this complexity, if you don't want to migrate I suggest you read up on RIM's networking APN, its a bit complex for a single stack overflow answer.

Comment: I try to load another images. they load fine. only in specific url the problem occurs. maybe its tied to a problematic urls?

Answer (score 0):

Add **";deviceside=true"** at the end of your url... like **"http://myHost/images/flux.jpg;deviceside=true"**, for Blackberry

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This occurs because i use POST method. I think in case that we dont send parametes but use method POST is occurs to problem with Content-Length in header of http message and this the reason that i recieve error(400 or 411)